# Google maps api works with the www.my-domain.com but not on my-domain.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a website which uses the google maps api.
I had to create a key on console.developers.google.com and did the domain verification and the map shows up ok when I access the website via www.my-domain.com.

However when I access it via my-domain.com (no "www.") I get an error on the console

```
TypeError: d is undefined on firefox
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` on chrome.
```

I've googled and it seems those errors are related to the API keys, so I did the domain verification for "my-domain.com", but the errors persist.

Is there something like a wild-card syntax I should be using when I verify the domain? Or maybe I should just remove the domain verification with the "www." and it will work for both cases?

Comment: Are both "*.my-domain.com/*" and "my-domain.com/*" allowed referrers for your key?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. How do I check that?

Comment: Also, why am I getting down voted?

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Just added the `my-domain.com/*` to the allowed referrers. Care to right an answer  so I can understand what was happening, and maybe explain if i should leave both verified domains or just one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow both "`*.my-domain.com/*`" and "`my-domain.com/*`" as "allowed referrers" for your key if you need both to work.

- `*.domain.com/*` matches any page or page in any folder of `http://www.domain.com` 
  (or any other subdomain of domain.com, www is a subdomain of domain.com)
- `domain.com/*`   matches any page or page in any folder of `http://domain.com`

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that when you change these settings, at least in firefox, you need to press the save button twice

Comment: Same under Chrome, @Davide: things seems a little bit buggy, even when you wait half an hour (Google says a potential 5 minutes delay may exists before changes are effective). Thanks to have noticed!